# Error while using ExtentReports in python webdriver script using Jpype

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, jpype

ExtentReports can be used in selenium java web-driver scripts to generate good and rich HTML test report. I am trying to use this in my selenium python web-driver script using JPype (JPype is an effort to allow python programs full access to java class libraries).
My code is like

```
from jpype import *
classpath = """lib\\extentreports-2.41.2.jar;lib\\freemarker-2.3.23.jar"""
startJVM(getDefaultJVMPath(), "-Djava.class.path=%s" % classpath)
ExtentReports = JClass('com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentReports')
ExtentTest = JClass('com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentTest')
LogStatus = JClass('com.relevantcodes.extentreports.LogStatus')
extent = ExtentReports("TestResult\\Test_Report.html")
test = extent.startTest("My First Test", "Sample description")
test.log(LogStatus.INFO, "This step shows usage of log(logStatus, details)")
extent.endTest(test)
extent.flush()
shutdownJVM()
```

And it give error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\test\workspace\ExtentReportsProject\ExtentReportsPackage\report.py", line 4, in <module>
ExtentReports = JClass('com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentReports')
File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\jpype1-0.6.2-py3.5-win-amd64.egg\jpype\_jclass.py", line 55, in JClass
raise _RUNTIMEEXCEPTION.PYEXC("Class %s not found" % name)
jpype._jexception.RuntimeExceptionPyRaisable: java.lang.RuntimeException: Class com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentReports not found
```

I am using extentreports-2.41.2.jar and freemarker-2.3.23.jar. Python used in 3.5.1 and Java 8 update 121

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer. Following code will work:

```
from jpype import *

classpath = """extentreports-2.40.2.jar;freemarker-2.3.23.jar"""
startJVM(getDefaultJVMPath(), "-Djava.class.path=%s" % classpath)
ExtentReports = JClass('com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentReports')
ExtentTest = JClass('com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentTest')
LogStatus = JClass('com.relevantcodes.extentreports.LogStatus')
extent = ExtentReports("Test_Report.html")

test = extent.startTest("Test Case 1", "Sample description")
test.log(LogStatus.INFO, "This step shows usage of log(logStatus, details)")
test.log(LogStatus.PASS, "Step Passed")
extent.flush()

test = extent.startTest("Test Case 2", "Sample description")
test.log(LogStatus.INFO, "This step shows usage of log(logStatus, details)")
test.log(LogStatus.PASS, "")
test.log(LogStatus.FAIL, "Step Passed")
extent.flush()

extent.endTest(test)
extent.flush()
shutdownJVM()
```